# Revit 2011 get the length of a wall

Tags: c#, revit

Has anyone got any code to get the length of a wall?  Currently I use:

```
ElementCategoryFilter wallsFilter = 
  new ElementCategoryFilter(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls);

FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(Doc);
IList<Element> walls =
  collector.WherePasses(wallsFilter).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements();

foreach (Element wall in walls)
  MessageBox.Show(wall.get_Parameter("Length").AsString());
```

Length comes back empty!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsString()` assumes that the parameter is of string type `(Parameter.StorageType == StorageType.String)`. This length parameter is a double length measurement.  So `AsDouble()` should work.  Or you can use `AsValueString()` to convert the value to a string with units as would be seen in the UI.

You could also switch to use `BuiltInParameter.CURVE_ELEM_LENGTH` instead of `"Length"` as a string.  This would be useful if the application is to be localized.